# ggvis numeric category sorting

Tags: r, ggvis

I have a data frame I'd like to create a bar plot for. The X axis will simply be the snapshot number, the y axis will be number of observations in that category. Unfortunately, I must convert the observation number to a character so ggvis() works. This breaks the sorting, since "2" > "10" for instance. I can't get both to work at the same time.

```
eachObs <-
structure(list(obs = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 
16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 
19, 20, 21, 22, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 
15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22), key = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), .Label = c("Sadness", 
"Neutral", "Contempt", "Disgust", "Anger", "Surprise", "Fear", 
"Happiness"), class = "factor"), value = c(0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 4, 4, 0, 0, 8, 4, 4, 68, 48, 44, 28, 
40, 28, 40, 36, 36, 40, 40, 44, 44, 40, 40, 44, 36, 36, 48, 40, 
60, 32, 12, 12, 4, 28, 8, 8, 4, 8, 20, 20, 24, 16, 16, 16, 12, 
20, 20, 0, 8, 4, 12, 12, 8, 4, 20, 12, 4, 12, 16, 12, 16, 12, 
8, 8, 4, 4, 8, 0, 16, 8, 4, 4, 4, 8, 0, 4, 8, 0, 4, 8, 4, 4, 
4, 0, 8, 8, 4, 8, 8, 0, 4, 8, 8, 4, 12, 8, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 20, 4, 0, 4, 4, 4, 8, 0, 16, 0, 12, 4, 12, 4, 0, 0, 4, 0, 
4, 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 16, 8, 20, 0, 8, 8, 
20, 12, 16, 32, 32, 24, 20, 20, 16, 16, 20, 28, 20, 24, 16, 20, 
20, 20, 8, 4, 28)), .Names = c("obs", "key", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 
-176L), class = "data.frame")
EMO_COLORS <- #used with the colors above
  c("blue", "grey", "darkred",
    "green", "red", "orange",
    "black", "yellow")
```

with this data, this returns an error

```
eachObs %>% 
    ggvis(x = ~obs, y = ~value, fill = ~key, fillOpacity := 0.5) %>%
    layer_bars() %>%
    scale_nominal("fill",
                  domain = unique(as.character(eachObs[, 'key'])),
                  range = EMO_COLORS)

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'key' not found
```

this fixes it, but creates the sorting problem

```
eachObs[, 1] <- as.character(eachObs[, 1])
eachObs %>% 
    ggvis(x = ~obs, y = ~value, fill = ~key, fillOpacity := 0.5) %>%
    layer_bars() %>%
    scale_nominal("fill",
                  domain = unique(as.character(eachObs[, 'key'])),
                  range = EMO_COLORS)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get better order, you can try:

```
eachObs[, 1] <- as.ordered(eachObs[, 1])
eachObs %>% 
        ggvis( x = ~obs, y = ~value, fill = ~key, fillOpacity := 0.5) %>%
        layer_bars()
```

This is what I get:
[image]

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem

Comment: It seems it solves the ordering problem, but your solution works as.well()

Comment: Apologies; when I tried it at first it didn't, but when I loaded it from a fresh session, it did. Not sure how that happened...

Answer (score 0):

this, just before the final plot, instead of the `as.character()`:

```
eachObs[, 1] <- as.factor(eachObs[, 1])
```